# delete duplicate rows in sql less than max value

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm having duplicate values in a table which I'm able to fetch using the below sql -

```
select p.*, j.job_id from (
    select count(job_id) cnt, title, email, msg_no from (
        select job_id, title, email, msg_no from job_posts order by job_id desc limit 500) as t 
    group by title, email, msg_no ) p 
left join job_posts j on p.title = j.title and p.email = j.email 
    and p.msg_no = j.msg_no where p.cnt >1
```

Now the result it's showing is something like -

```
cnt  |  title          |    email         | msg_no | job_id
2    | some title      | simon@domain.com |  123   | 210
2    | some title      | simon@domain.com |  123   | 209
2    | some title      | simon@domain.com |  123   | 208
2    | another title   | bob@domain.com   |  243   | 329
2    | another title   | bob@domain.com   |  243   | 328
```

Now I want to delete only the rows having job_id less than the max value for a unique row

i.e i want to delete these rows -

```
cnt  |  title          |    email         | msg_no | job_id
2    | some title      | simon@domain.com |  123   | 209
2    | some title      | simon@domain.com |  123   | 208
2    | another title   | bob@domain.com   |  243   | 328
```

Comment: You can GROUP BY your data once more

Comment: @Serg oh wow not in max(job_id) nice ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pattern:

```
DELETE t1.*
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 USING ( {common columns} )
WHERE t1.criteria_column < t2.criteria_column
```

Comment: not in max(job_id) also works but this join works out mysteriously like a voodoo. Nice

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya `not in max(job_id)` is obviously slower.

Answer (score 0):

With sample data like ...

```sql
Create Table IF NOT EXISTS job_posts (job_id Int, 
                                      title VarChar(16), 
                                      email VarChar(32), 
                                      msg_no Int);
                                      
Insert Into job_posts (job_id, title, email, msg_no) VALUES
(105, 'single title X', 'mike@domain.com', 103),
(104, 'single title Y', 'anna@domain.com', 103),
  
(210, 'some title', 'simon@domain.com', 123), 
(209, 'some title', 'simon@domain.com', 123), 
(208, 'some title', 'simon@domain.com', 123),
(329, 'another title', 'bob@domain.com', 243), 
(328, 'another title', 'bob@domain.com', 243);

Select * From job_posts Order By job_id;
/*
job_id  title               email              msg_no
------  ------------------  -----------------  ------
   104  single title Y      anna@domain.com       103
   105  single title X      mike@domain.com       103
   208  some title          simon@domain.com      123
   209  some title          simon@domain.com      123
   210  some title          simon@domain.com      123
   328  another title       bob@domain.com        243
   329  another title       bob@domain.com        243  */
```

... one option to isolate repeating data rows is to use Count() Over() analytic function ...

```sql
SELECT x.job_id
FROM 
  ( Select job_id, 
           Count(job_id) Over(Partition By title, email, msg_no Order By job_id Desc
                          Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as row_nmbr,
           Count(job_id) Over(Partition By title, email, msg_no) as num_of_rows
    From   job_posts
  ) x
WHERE num_of_rows > 1 And row_nmbr > 1
/*
job_id
------
   328
   209
   208     */
```

... the above code selects job_ids that you want to delete, so use it in Where clause to filter your delete action.

```sql
DELETE FROM job_posts
WHERE job_id IN( SELECT x.job_id
                 FROM 
                   ( Select job_id, 
                            Count(job_id) Over(Partition By title, email, msg_no Order By job_id Desc
                                               Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as row_nmbr,
                            Count(job_id) Over(Partition By title, email, msg_no) as num_of_rows
                     From   job_posts
                   ) x
                 WHERE num_of_rows > 1 And row_nmbr > 1
               );
```

... checking the table content after delete ...

```sql
Select * From job_posts;
/*
job_id  title               email              msg_no
------  ------------------  -----------------  ------
   105  single title X      mike@domain.com       103
   104  single title Y      anna@domain.com       103
   210  some title          simon@domain.com      123
   329  another title       bob@domain.com        243  */
```

Answer (score 0):

For each pair of (title,email,msg_no) find the largest job_id and create the tupel (title/email/msg_no/largest_job_id).

Delete all rows not matching those tupels:

```
DELETE FROM job_posts 
WHERE
    CONCAT(title, '/', email, '/', msg_no, '/', job_id) NOT IN (
        SELECT 
            CONCAT(title, '/', email, '/', msg_no, '/', MAX(job_id)) AS uniq_job
        FROM job_posts
        GROUP BY title, email, msg_no
    );
```

Comment: wow without any table structure we can create tables. Will try that

Comment: Actually, even the create temp table in my first version isn't required...

Comment: this will select all the rows, i want only the rows with duplicates

Comment: The inner SELECT fetches all rows you want to keep, the outer DELETE will delete all rows __NOT IN__ that selection, i.e. the duplicates.